# What is preventing Firefox from opening websites?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I **solved** my problem but I want to know what caused it for any future reference and better understanding.

---

I have come across a strange behavior of Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04. I left office with my laptop turned on so I could listen to music. Before I left office, Firefox was working normally.

Now I came to library, opened my laptop and Firefox and what happened was that Firefox was unable to open any pages, including Google.com. Firefox was running smoothly, without any delays, it just returned *Server not found* on any page I tried.  What I did was, as usual in such cases, restart `NetworkManager` with command

```
sudo killall NetworkManager
```

which also automatically starts `NetworkManager` after it. The laptop connected to network, I relaunch Firefox and again nothing. So I ran

```
ps auxw | grep firefox
```

to see if there is some strange Firefox background process running but everything appeared as usual. I am sorry but I didn't take a screenshot, my mistake. I closed Firefox and executed `ps auxw | grep firefox` again and as expected, there was only one output line like this

```
campovs+  2715  0.0  0.0   5924  2196 pts/0    S+   16:43   0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

which means that `grep` was searching for `firefox`.

At this point I was 100% sure there has to be something with the internet connection and not Firefox. So I decided to proceed with regular internet connection checking, that being executing

```
ping google.com
```

Packets were flying which also eliminated possible DNS errors, although I have no idea how those could happen since I haven't done anything on my laptop and the network I was connected to was *eduroam*. I ran another command

```
curl -v google.com
```

and it, as expected, returned HTML code of `google.com` with last line

```
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```

which basically means everything is ok. I was left out of options and I knew that restarting the laptop will almost certainly solve the problem, although I didn't even know what was causing it. I ran `sudo reboot` and now Firefox is working.

**So my question is, does anyone of you know, what might cause such behavior?**

Comment: just to confirm; is the firefox process name "FireFox" or "Firefox" or "firefox"? Just wondering if there was a process out there that you missed by searching for the purely lower-cased version.

Comment: @JeffSchaller firefox process should always spawn in all-lowers as long as I know.

Comment: @JeffSchaller firefox normally started, everything was working fine but it didn't load websites. Instead it returned Page not found. I will include that in question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a an issue Firefox, which might be related to the huge amount of memory it uses.

Firefox support pages suggest some ideas which you already performed:

- Restart firefox
- Restart your computer

More troubleshooting ideas and suggestions can be found here:

- [firefox-hangs-or-not-responding](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hangs-or-not-responding)
- [troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems)

Comment: Firefox indeed uses a lot of memory, over 2GB, but I don't see why this would be and issue since computer was running without problems, firefox dind't have any problems running, opening new tabs, typing, closing, resizing... Besides there should have been at least 4GB of RAM unused at that point (max 1.2GB for Ubuntu, 2GB for Firefox, and a tiny bit for Terminal).

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue often when I suspend my laptop and move locations.  When the laptop wakes up, Firefox will not find any websites for a long time, but will eventually start working.

I found the solution on this url https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can, under 'DNS Prefetching'.

1. in the address bar, type **about:config** and press enter.
2. Right-click in the list, select **New**, and then **Boolean**.
3. In the name field type **network.dns.disablePrefetch** and click **Ok**.
4. If the new item is **false**, right click and toggle the value.
5. Verify that you can now load pages.
6. Toggle the value back to **false**.

I suspect that if I run into this issue again and toggle the value from **true** to **false**, that it will fix the issue.

Comment: This seems to be only one cause of the issue.  I had the issue again, and the solution didn't work.